# Compare NSArray with NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have one NSArray with objects {3, 5, 6} and a NSDictionary with {3, 5} i want to compare those and delete the "6" because its missing from the NSDictionary i'm using the following code

```
[lists enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

     Item *item = (Item *)obj;
     NSString *value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", item.remoteID];

     for (NSDictionary *dictionary in responseObject)
     {
         NSString *idValue = [dictionary objectForKey:@"id"];

         if ([value isEqualToString:idValue])
         {
            NSLog(@"value %@", value);
         }
     }
```

}];

```
NSLog(@"value %@", value);
```

here i'm getting the correct values but i want to get the missing values in my case "6"

any ideas welcome.

Comment: A dictionary with 3,5 what? Are those keys or is 3 the key and 5 the value?

Comment: please explain your data structures.. (like the output of "po responseObject", "po lists")

Comment: NSArray output <Item: 0xa8376a0> (entity: Item; id: 0xa836840 <x-coredata://CB7847D7-551B-4027-A720-21E65B94E4C9/Item/p107> ; data: {
    remoteID = 2589;
}) NSString *idValue = [dictionary objectForKey:@"id"]; is just a dictionary of strings

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have an array `lists` and an array `responseObject` of dictionaries, which contain an `id` key with the object you want to compare to the array `lists`.

```
NSArray *lists = @[@3, @5, @6];
NSArray *responseObject = @[@{@"id":@3},@{@"id":@5}];
```

Then, you could do something like this to get "the missing values":

```
NSArray *idValues = [responseObject valueForKey:@"id"];
//Subset of objects in lists that are not present in idValues:
NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:lists];
[result removeObjectsInArray:idValues];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to go about this.

If you wish to look at it as a filtering task in which you filter the `lists` array by the `id` values in the `responseObject`, then a simple predicate will do:

```
NSPredicate *responsePred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"self IN %@", [responseObject valueForKey: @"id"]];
NSArray *result = [lists filteredArrayUsingPredicate: responsePred];
```